# pygsm - sending and responding to sms in addition to what I already have

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, sms

Hello StackOverflow,

here we go once again.
I've created an algorithm which sends a formated string (coming from an Arduino) to a user per SMS every 60 seconds. Now I want to add a module which let's me write a message to the Raspberry and to get that string immediately.

I know the library pygsm can do that but I haven't figured it out yet. 
The program I'm posting should technically work but doesn't. It never changes the msg variable even though I'm sending SMS to the modem.

```
import time
from pygsm import GsmModem
# connect to the modem
#modem = pygsm.GsmModem(port="/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200)
modem = GsmModem(port="/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200).boot()

# check for new messages every two
# seconds for the rest of forever
msg = []
while True:
        msg = modem.next_message()
        print msg
# we got a message! respond with
# something useless, as an example
        if msg is not None:
                msg.respond("Thanks for those %d characters!" %
                len(msg.text))
        else:
                time.sleep(2)
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you assign `msg` first to an empty list and then to `modem.next_message()`?

Comment: @Tagc probably not the best idea, I figured to make sure it's empty first and from what I understand, the modem.next_message() only fills msg if it receives an sms. When I print the msg (like I do) it always says "None". I wouldn't want it to say a random value when something is stored in it beforehand, so I clear it.

Comment: That's not how that works at all. `msg` will *always* be assigned some definite value when `msg = modem.next_message()` is executed (not familiar with `pygsm` but I guess either `None` or an actual message). Try removing the `msg = []` assignment in your code and see if you notice any difference.

Comment: @Tagc doesn't change a thing.